# How to change App Display Name in Expo Managed app after publishing to App Store?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

We have an Expo managed app. Initially we’ve set `expo.name` to `Bridge - Debit Card` in `app.json` file. We successfully released it into both stores - App Store and Google Play.

But later we noticed that app display name (the app name on device desktop right under the app icon) looks clumsy. It looks like `BridgeDe...` on iOS.

So, we changed expo.name to simply `Bridge`, rebuilt the standalone app, and posted new binaries into both app stores again.

Google Play just ate new binaries without any problems, the new short app name appeared on Android devices.

But we can’t pass Apple verification during uploading `.ipa` file. We use `Transporter` app on Mac. It shows an error:

> ITMS-90129: The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken.

But we have no apps with such name in AppStore.

We tried to return `expo.name` to old value `Bridge - Debit Card` and add `CFBundleDisplayName` (and later `CFBundleName`) with Bridge value into `expo.ios.infoPlist`, but no luck: app released in AppStore just fine (verification passed with old `expo.name`), but has a long and truncated name under app icon. So, that option simply didn't do a trick, nothing changed.

This is an `app.json` example of our app:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Bridge - Debit Card",
    "slug": "bridge-debit-card",
    "owner": "bridge",
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "1.0.4",
      "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleDisplayName": "Bridge",
      }
   }
}
```

Could someone suggest a solution how to achieve our goal: have shorter app name on device desktop and longer name in the App Store listings? Important note that our apps already published. I don't want to `eject` and change `bundleIdentifier`.

I will appreciate any help, any idea!

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

I figured out how to resolve this issue. The first time you create a build (using eas build) and submit it to App Store Connect, Expo will provide the `name` property from `app.json` as the name  of your app's App Store listing (which has to be unique) and your app's display name (which is shown on the home screen and does not have to be unique). If you rebuild your app in a new version and change the `name` property in `app.json` to something else, only your app's display name will change, not your app's unique App Store listing name.

Comment: I had this issue for a full day and you resolved it! All I had to do was change my version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 !